# Wrong click area on GUI.Button in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I build a simple GUI menu. In this menu I have 5 buttons. In this example, each button has a number (see attached picture).

Wehen I click on the button with the number **1**, my script recognizes the click correctly and shows me the log for button **1**.
When I click on button **2** my script shows me the log for button **1**. When I click on the button with number **4** I get the log for button number **2**.

I changed the height of each button to the exact height but this didn't fixed it. Any idea, why the click area of the buttons is so big? (Only in the vertical direction)

The code: (childNavStyle is just a public GUIStyle with nothing special. Image attached)

```
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(GUIx, GUIy, 45, 45), "1", childNavStyle)) {
            Debug.Log("1");
        }
        if(GUI.Button(new Rect(GUIx, GUIy, 45, 45), "2", childNavStyle)) {
            Debug.Log ("2");
        }
        GUI.Button(new Rect(GUIx, GUIy, 45, 45), "3", childNavStyle);
        GUI.Button(new Rect(GUIx, GUIy, 45, 45), "4", childNavStyle);
        GUI.Button(new Rect(GUIx, GUIy, 45, 45), "5", childNavStyle);
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Added it to my question :)

Comment: I'm confused about how the code given is generating that screenshot. The buttons are all being created in exactly the same position with exactly the same dimensions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I removed some lines to make it more readable for you. The screenshot was just a test output. I simply added some numbers to the variable "GUIy"